# Texture goes strange when baked

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I'm having a very strange problem in blender (I'm aware that its probably me that is the problem, not blender as I am a newbie but anyway) I have a simple character and when I UV unwrap it, there are some weird lines that occur (I think they are the eyes):

[image]

When I bake the texture it looks like this:

[image]

When I have all the different textures applied, the body looks fine, but as soon as I get rid of those textures and apply the baked one, there is a strange patch on the lower back, which I am assuming is to do with the strange unwrap.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any tips on how to fix this? thanks :)

Comment: You have to mark seams before unwrapping. https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/seams.html

Comment: I have marked seams

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it in the end. It would seem that it was because of some internal faces which were located near the eyes. I deleted those and rebaked and now it works :D